# How can we add event listener to DOM changes inside iframe when there is a cross origin issue?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, cross-browser

I have an iframe inside the body of an html page. Inside the iframe there is another html page. Iframe has the src='https://binge.com'. For the first time when the contents of the iframe loads (i.e. https://binge.com) my event handler onreadystatechange gets called. But when I search something in binge.com and I go to some different location my iframe scr doesn't change but content of html does which is fine. Also onreadystatechange function doesn't execute. I am not sure why is that the case? How can I access the changes like url when user navigates away from https://binge.com? and why does my src of iframe doesn't change? Also, due to cross origin issue I can't directy access the changed url inside the iframe.

I am new to javascript. Any lead would be really helpful.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style>
        body,html,iframe{
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
        }
    </style>
    <meta>
    <meta>
    <meta>
</head>
<body>

    <iframe src="" id="iframe">  </iframe>


    <script type="text/javascript">
            document.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (document.readyState == "complete") {
                    abc();
                }
            }

    function abc() {

    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can’t

I tried to do this exact problem that you have, when the page first loads on your specified src you can access the iframe’s contents because the src was specified from the server end and is assumed to be safe, as soon as the page within the src changes, the javascript can no longer access the content because it can not be guaranteed if it is safe/secure to do so. For example, you could load a website that has malware on it so the javascript blocks access. If you programmatically change the src e.g. `document.getElementById("myIframe").src = "www.example.com";` your event should fire but not if the iframes page is changed from within the iframe.

Hope this helps

Alternatively, you could look into setting up a proxy-server script and link an iframe to your script that could also return the contents of each page back to your webpage